# MYSQL сложный LIKE

Tags: mysql, регулярные-выражения

Привет, делаю поиск на mysql.
Пользователь ввел поисковый запрос 'John Smith',
нужно получить строки, где подстрока запроса встречается в различных комбинациях

1)

> **John smith** loren ipsum ...
>
> ...Loren ipsum **john smith**.
>
> ...Loren **john smith** ipsum....

2)

> Loren **john** ipsum **smith** amet

Пытаюсь составить запрос. С пунктом 2 все понятно:

```
SELECT * 
    FROM  `person` 
    WHERE memo LIKE  '% John % Smith %'
```

С пунктом 1 нет. 
Запрос:

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `person` 
WHERE memo LIKE  '%John%Smith%'
```

вернет нам в том числе и такие строки:

> Loren el**john**athan ipsum le**smith**el amet

А мне это не нужно, нужны строки, как указаны в пункте 1.

Я так понимаю, нужно использовать regexp?  
Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В вашем случае лучше использовать полнотекстовый поиск в MySQL.
В двух словах не расскажешь, есть целая статья по этому вопросу.
Сам одно время делал "умный" поиск, но я тогда еще обрезал каждое слово на 1-2 символа с конца, чтобы поиск лучше понимал склонения разных слов.
Подробнее почитайте вот тут: http://www.mysql.ru/docs/man/Fulltext_Search.html

Answer (score 0):

Пробелы перед и после слов?

```
WHERE memo LIKE '% John Smith %'
```

Comment: Да, таким образом мы отсекем совпадения типа таких lujohn Smithy

Answer (score 0):

Вариант с [регулярными выражениями](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html) (на случай, если решите обойтись ими):

```
SELECT * 
FROM person
WHERE memo REGEXP '[[:<:]]John[[:>:]]'
AND memo REGEXP '[[:<:]]Smith[[:>:]]'
```